# Plotly histogram starts with negative value, even though none in data

Tags: pandas, plotly

[image]

Hi all! When plotting the distribution of data with Plotly, I've noticed that the histogram bins start at a negative value (here -0.25) even though my dataset has no negative value (see below the mins, avg_time_per_user here starts at 0).

I've tried playing around with the number of bins which makes no difference. The only thing that makes the histogram correctly start at 0 is removing `nbins=n` entirely, which is not ideal as I want to be able to control it.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution while Googling some more: using a dict to define the bins. This worked like a charm in having the correct first bin delimitation.

```
fig.update_traces(xbins=dict( 
        start=0.0,
        end=5.0,
        size=0.5))
```

[image]